# How to control .glb model animations in A-FRAME via Three.js

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, aframe, gltf

I'm trying to play a glb animation in A-FRAME with Three.js,
now it works just for a second and then it stop, could someone help me please?
this is my code:

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('move', {
  init: function () {
    setTimeout( () => {
      let position = this.el.getAttribute("position")
   console.log(this.el.components['gltf-model'].model )
            // Create an AnimationMixer, and get the list of AnimationClip instances
      const mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( this.el.components['gltf-model'].model);
      const clips = this.el.components['gltf-model'].model.animations[0];
      var clock = new THREE.Clock();
      // Play all animations

    mixer.clipAction( clips ).play();
   //In the animation block of your scene:
      var delta = 0.25 * clock.getDelta();
      mixer.update( delta );
    }, 2000)
  }
})
</script>

  <a-scene>
      <a-entity gltf-model="https://rawcdn.githack.com/BabylonJS/MeshesLibrary/55f475726670be2e7e4017b5f88c5762a90508c2/shark.glb" move position=".5 0.5 -5" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5"></a-entity>                                                        
  </a-scene>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Wait until the model is loaded with:

   ```
   this.el.addEventListener("model-loaded", evt => /* stuff */)}
   ```
2. update the animation in the renderloop  - on each [`tick`](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/core/component.html#tick-time-timedelta). You could use an interval or something else, but aframe has already a built-in function for this purpose:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent('move', {
    init: function() {
      // wait until the model is loaded
      this.el.addEventListener("model-loaded", evt => {
        const mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(this.el.components['gltf-model'].model);
        const clips = this.el.components['gltf-model'].model.animations[0];
        mixer.clipAction(clips).play();
        // "expose" the animation mixer
        this.mixer = mixer;
      })
    },
    // on each render loop (actually before each render loop)
    tick: function(t, dt) {
      if (!this.mixer) return; // if the mixer exists
      this.mixer.update(dt / 1000) // update it with the delta time
    }
  })
</script>

<a-scene>
  <a-entity gltf-model="https://rawcdn.githack.com/BabylonJS/MeshesLibrary/55f475726670be2e7e4017b5f88c5762a90508c2/shark.glb"
  move position=".5 0.5 -5" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 2):

To control animation in a-frame is to use predefined animation-mixer component by aframe extra's.

```
<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/donmccurdy/aframe-extras@v6.1.1/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-entity id="model"
      gltf-model="https://rawcdn.githack.com/BabylonJS/MeshesLibrary/55f475726670be2e7e4017b5f88c5762a90508c2/shark.glb"
      position=".5 0.5 -5" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5"></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("model").setAttribute("animation-mixer", "clip:swimming");
    const timedelay = setTimeout(delayFunction, 2000);
    function delayFunction() {
      document.getElementById("model").setAttribute("animation-mixer", "clip:bite");
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

where you can set the required animation to clip attribute and play any animation based on your program logic. Use this for [reference](https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-extras/blob/master/src/loaders/animation-mixer.js) if any. Here in my code swimming animation plays first and after 2 seconds bite animation plays.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @ajai.s, 
in fact I started using the animation-mixer component, the problem is that I can't select the frames I need from the animation while in three.js I can easily use the "subclip" command like this: `const Action1 = THREE.AnimationUtils.subclip(clip, 'swim', 0, 80);`

Comment: In animation mixer similar to clip there are a few basic options to control the animation. They are startFrame, timeScale, Repetition you can use these to achieve subclip like threejs. Refer code here https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-extras/blob/master/src/loaders/animation-mixer.js

Comment: ok I've try but is not possible to set start and stop frame like in three.js.. there is only startFrame option but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: startFrame is not based on frames here it is described in terms of time. Try this or you can make your own animation in blender and store it to a different name. So it can be easily set based on your logic.